# how to find cube root without decimal numbers in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the cube root of 64

**I tried:**

```
64**(1/3)
```

It works with other numbers like 8 and 27, but in this case

**it returned**

```
3.9999999999999996
```

is there any way to get the correct cube root?